# How do you use tweepy to search for tweets within a given timeframe?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I basically want to look for tweets that contain a keyword between two tweets. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy



CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'
ACCESS_KEY = '...'
ACCESS_SECRET = '...'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

results = api.search(q="keyword", since_id=..., max_id=...)

for result in results:
    print (result.text)
```

However no matter how far apart, or how common my keyword is, it only ever gets 15 tweets. Is there anyway to return all tweets during this time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search) you need to use `rpp` keyword parameter to increase number of tweets per page. Twitter API returns 15 tweets if the parameter was not set in a request.

Note, that [Twitter search API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) returns no more than 100 tweets per page.